# How to identify whether a video is recorded or picked form savedPhotosAlbum inside imagePickerController(_: didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:) method

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

In my swift application, I have a “Record Video” functionality as well as a “Play Video” functionality. 
I have used the delegate method [imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontrollerdelegate/1619126-imagepickercontroller) to handle both the functionalities. In each case, the whole code inside the function is running.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, 
      didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
      //code
}
```

[image: imagepickercontroller preview video]

Within this function, how can I specifically know whether the video I am handling is a **recorded** one or **picked** from the savedPhotosAlbum?

Comment: You will most likely find this information within the `info` dictionary. Can you set a breakpoint within the method and check what the keys in `info` are? This will probably point you in the direction you want to go.

Comment: Thank you @DavidChopin. Picked video had 3 elements in `info` dictionary `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL`, `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL` and `UIImagePickerControllerMediaType`. And the recorded video had only `UIImagePickerControllerMediaType` and `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL`. Now I can handle the watch video functionality by checking `if (info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] != nil)`.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

switch picker.sourceType {

case .camera:
     // Recorded


case .photoLibrary, .savedPhotosAlbum:
    // picked from Photos library


default: break
}



   }
```

Comment: Thanks @K4747Z. This works for me.!  Unfortunately I cannot vote for the answer as I am with less than 15 reputation. :D